# Missing Function Error in Count

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 data tables, Employees and Departments. I want to show the department numbers, department names, the number of employees in each department, the average salary of each department, the employee names, their salaries, and jobs IDs of the employees. Here's what I wrote for my code:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, e.count(*) Employees,   
avg(e.salary) Avg_salary, e.last_name, e.salary, e.job_id
from departments d join employees e
on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by d.department_id, d.department_name, e.last_name, e.salary, e.job_id 
order by d.department_id;
```

However, the error "Missing Function" appears when I run the code. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`e.count(*)` should just be `count(*)`.

EDIT:

Is this what you need?

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e.department_id) DeptCt
```

Comment: This doesn't work; it just shows the number per employee entry separately. I want to show the total number of employees in each department.

Comment: I tried running your new edit code, but a "not a group by function" error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT d.department_id, 
       d.department_name, 
       Count(*)      Employees, 
       Avg(e.salary) Avg_salary, 
       e.last_name, 
       e.salary, 
       e.job_id 
FROM   departments d 
       JOIN employees e 
         ON d.department_id = e.department_id 
GROUP  BY d.department_id, 
          d.department_name, 
          e.last_name, 
          e.salary, 
          e.job_id 
ORDER  BY d.department_id;
```

Comment: I run your code, and the count simply returns 1 for each employee entry, not accumulatively. Say the Marketing Department has 3 employees. I want the count to show 3, but you code simply returns 1 three separate times.